# Как обратиться к переменной из другого класса

Tags: java, json, selenium

Есть 2 класса  и 2ом мне необходимо передать данные из gsonData в качестве текста,но я никак не могу к нему обратиться
1ый weatherParse

```
package testClassPackage;

import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class WeatherParse {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String sURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/?q=Odessa,ua&APPID=518a64dd48106aa542464d3bd94d12ce"; //just a string


        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
        request.connect();


        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray message = rootobj.get("list").getAsJsonArray();
        Map<String, String> data = new TreeMap<>();

        for (JsonElement lst : message) {
            JsonObject lstObject = lst.getAsJsonObject();
            JsonObject el = (JsonObject) lstObject.get("main");
//            System.out.println(lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString() + " " + el.get("temp").getAsString());
            if (lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString().contains(" 12")) {

                data.put("Дата " + lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString(), "Прогноз День:" + el.get("temp").getAsString());
            } else if (lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString().contains(" 21")) {
                data.put("Дата " + lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString(), "Прогноз Ночь:" + el.get("temp").getAsString());
            }

        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type gsonType = new TypeToken<TreeMap>() {
        }.getType();
        String gsonData = gson.toJson(data, gsonType);
        System.out.println(gsonData);


    }
}
```

2ой
testWeatherChrome

```
package testClassPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class testWeatherChrome {
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        initDriver.getInstance("chrome");
    }

    @Test
    public void getTitle() throws InterruptedException {
        String URL ="https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=ru&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%3Fgws_rd%3Dssl&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin";
        initDriver.driver.get(URL);
        initDriver.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"identifierId\"]")).sendKeys("lesha.test11111@gmail.com");
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()=\"Далее\"]")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(initDriver.driver, 10);
        WebElement passwordElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"password\"]")));
//        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"password\"]")).sendKeys("Lesshasugurov11111");
        passwordElement.sendKeys("Lesshasugurov11111");
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()=\"Далее\"]")).click();
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()=\"Почта\"]")).click();
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()=\"Написать\"]")).click();
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@aria-label=\"Кому\"]")).sendKeys("lesha.test111@gmail.com");
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label=\"Тема\"]")).sendKeys("Погода на неделю для Одессы");
        WeatherParse w = new WeatherParse();
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=\":6g\"]")).sendKeys(WeatherParse.gsonData);

    }


//    @AfterClass
//    public void close() {
//        initDriver.quit();
//    }

}
```

Comment: Опиши вопрос более подробно, какая ошибка возникает, так ничего не понятно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вынести логику взятия прогноза погоды в отдельный метод

```
public getWeather() {
   // тут все содержимое метода main()
   return gsonData;
}
```

Затем из других мест просто вызывайте

```
new WeatherParse().getWeather();
```

PS: можно там же кэшировать данные, чтобы на каждый вызов getWeather() не стучаться в интернет.